MLP with single hidden layer implemented form scratch with pytorch
My code is like this:
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils import data
import torchvision


#==============load dataset
def get_dataloader_workers():
    return 4


def load_data_fashion_mnist(batch_size,resize=None):
    trans = [transforms.ToTensor()]
    if resize:
        trans.insert(0,transforms.Resize(resize))
    trans = transforms.Compose(trans)
    mnist_train = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(
        root="../data",train=True,transform=trans,download=True)
    mnist_test = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(
        root="../data", train=False, transform=trans, download=True)
    return (data.DataLoader(mnist_train,batch_size,shuffle=True,num_workers=get_dataloader_workers()),
            data.DataLoader(mnist_test,batch_size,shuffle=False,num_workers=get_dataloader_workers()))

batch_size = 256
train_iter,test_iter = load_data_fashion_mnist(batch_size)

#=============model Params
num_inputs, num_outputs, num_hiddens = 784,10,256

# param initialization
W1 = torch.randn((num_inputs,num_hiddens),requires_grad=True)*0.01
b1 = torch.zeros(num_hiddens,requires_grad=True)

W2 = torch.randn((num_hiddens,num_outputs),requires_grad=True)*0.01
b2 = torch.zeros(num_outputs,requires_grad=True)


#===========activation func
def relu(X):
    a = torch.zeros_like(X)
    return torch.max(X,a)

def softmax(X):
    Exp_x = torch.exp(X- X.max(dim=1, keepdim=True)[0])
    partition = Exp_x.sum(axis=1,keepdim=True)
    return Exp_x / partition

#===========model
def mlp(X):
    """接收输入数据"""
    X = X.reshape((-1,num_inputs)) #展平图像为784的长度
    H = relu(torch.matmul(X,W1) + b1)    #隐藏层
    O = softmax(torch.matmul(H,W2) + b2)

    return O

def cross_entropy_loss(y_hat,y):
    return -torch.log(y_hat[range(len(y_hat)),y])


def sgd(params,lr,batch_size):
    """minibatch sgd"""
    with torch.no_grad():
        for param in params:
            param -= lr*param.grad/batch_size
            param.grad.zero_()


lr = 0.03
num_epochs = 3
net = mlp
loss = cross_entropy_loss

def train():
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for X,y in train_iter:

            y_hat = net(X)
            print(y_hat[0])
            print(y_hat.shape)
            print(y)

            l = loss(y_hat,y)
            print("The shape of loss: ",l.shape)

            l.sum().backward()
            assert b2.grad is not None,"b2.grad is none"
            assert W2.grad is not None,"W2.grad is none"

            sgd([W1,b1,W2,b2],lr,batch_size)

        with torch.no_grad():
            train_l = loss(net(X),y).mean()
            print(f' epoch {epoch+1}, loss {float(train_l.mean()):f}')

if __name__=="__main__":
    train()

when I ran the code ,an exception occureenter image description here
But I checked the forward pass, the backward pass,still confused me.
Can anyone help to fix this code? Please help me!
I had tried to print the b2.grad, it works;
But when i print W2.grad, it failed with W2.grad is none Exception
